# UIScrollView: showing white line over view at the time of swiping for second and disappearing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have created a horizontal paging view controller using scroll view . I have created  fixed size scrollview and when swipe happens i am adding new view controller to scroll view every time . Every thing is going absolutely correct .
But now i am facing a problem , when i am swiping then a thin white line is flushing over my view controller for a second and disappears .

My scroll view code is below :

```
    contentScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)];
[contentScroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

And i am  just adding new view controller when swipe happens see below code :

```
        UIViewController *contentVC = [UIViewController new];
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) * index, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), contentScroll.bounds.size.height)];
    contentVC.view.frame = contentView.bounds;
    contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [contentView addSubview:contentVC.view];
    [contentVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self addChildViewController:contentVC];

    [contentScroll addSubview:contentVC.view];
```

This scrollView is added to my view controller's view.

Comment: did you fix this as I am also facing the same problem?